# Docker build & deploy on Jenkins takes increasingly long amount of time

Tags: .net, docker, jenkins

I have a small .NET Core web application running in a Docker container that is built and deployed in Jenkins. The docker repository is hosted via Quay.

Initially, it took less than a minute to build & deploy the container. But over time each build & deploy has taken an increasingly long amount of time, to where it is now up to over an hour. Here are some hopefully relevant portions from the beginning of the log:

**checking out out the repository from git:**

```
...
+ ./build.sh
+ REPO=quay.io/my/dir
+ IMAGE=quay.io/my/dir:dddaca1fd347b1fabea342a6a65431b68f793ad4
+ docker pull quay.io/my/dir
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from my/dir
Digest: sha256:9a654ad205764a668c1fc531c0972d1273b0920dc8282a8c7b6498482cee7975
Status: Image is up to date for quay.io/my/dir:latest
+ docker build -t quay.io/my/dir:dddaca1fd347b1fabea342a6a65431b68f793ad4 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 121.9 kB
Sending build context to Docker daemon 121.9 kB
...
```

**pushing the docker image, I think:**

```
...
+ '[' true = true ']'
+ docker tag -f quay.io/my/dir:dddaca1fd347b1fabea342a6a65431b68f793ad4 quay.io/my/dir:latest
+ '[' true = true ']'
+ docker tag -f quay.io/my/dir:dddaca1fd347b1fabea342a6a65431b68f793ad4 quay.io/my/dir:latest-master
+ docker tag -f quay.io/my/dir:dddaca1fd347b1fabea342a6a65431b68f793ad4 quay.io/my/dir:master-62
+ docker push quay.io/my/dir
The push refers to a repository [quay.io/my/dir] (len: 26)
...
```

**Then the time is taken up mostly by reams of the following:**

```
...
7db029aae55d: Preparing
7db029aae55d: Pushing
7db029aae55d: Pushed
55d4937daea6: Preparing
55d4937daea6: Pushing
55d4937daea6: Pushed
7ed278cf0e04: Preparing
7ed278cf0e04: Pushing
7ed278cf0e04: Pushed
master-49: digest: sha256:8ce1e...<more of the key>...90503 size: 21007
4c16f41d1cc1: Image already exists
8f1aae847e7a: Image already exists
28a352fdaf13: Image already exists
80151bfc7fc5: Image already exists
54c7eb98ce04: Preparing
54c7eb98ce04: Pushing
54c7eb98ce04: Pushed
b1131d0b29bb: Preparing
... more of the same
```

I'm a newbie to Docker and would appreciate some kind help. Here is my `build.sh` and `Dockerfile`:

**build.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash -ex

REPO=quay.io/my/dir
IMAGE=$REPO:$GIT_COMMIT

docker pull $REPO
docker build -t $IMAGE .
docker run --rm $IMAGE /bin/bash -c "cd /app/test/Project.Tests && dotnet test"

if [ "$TAG_LATEST" = true ]; then
    docker tag -f $IMAGE $REPO:latest
fi

if [ "$TAG_LATEST_MASTER" = true ]; then
    docker tag -f $IMAGE $REPO:latest-master
fi

# $TAG defined prior to running script
docker tag -f $IMAGE $REPO:$TAG

docker push $REPO
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.1.1-sdk

EXPOSE 5000

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN cd src/Project && dotnet restore --configfile NuGet.config --no-cache
RUN cd test/Project.Tests && dotnet restore --no-cache
RUN dotnet build

WORKDIR /app/src/Project
CMD ["dotnet", "run", "--server.urls", "https://0.0.0.0:5000"]
```

**Image History**

```
$ sudo docker history quay.io/my/dir
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
0e58e5457605        4 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) CMD ["dotnet" "run" "--s...   0B
<missing>           4 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) WORKDIR /app/src/Project    0B
<missing>           4 days ago          /bin/sh -c dotnet build                         782kB
<missing>           4 days ago          /bin/sh -c cd test/Project.Tests && dotn...   15.8MB
<missing>           4 days ago          /bin/sh -c cd src/Project && dotnet rest...   2.4MB
<missing>           4 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) WORKDIR /app                  0B
<missing>           4 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:c9cbed0051facc2...   62kB
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) EXPOSE 5000/tcp               0B
<missing>           4 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c mkdir warmup     && cd warmup  ...   297MB
<missing>           4 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV NUGET_XMLDOC_MODE=skip   0B
<missing>           4 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c curl -SL $DOTNET_SDK_DOWNLOAD_U...   290MB
<missing>           4 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV DOTNET_SDK_DOWNLOAD...   0B
<missing>           4 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV DOTNET_SDK_VERSION=...   0B
<missing>           4 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c apt-get update     && apt-get i...   1.64MB
<missing>           4 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get insta...   123MB
<missing>           4 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get insta...   44.6MB
<missing>           4 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/bash"]            0B
<missing>           4 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:f4e6551ac34ab44...   124MB
```

Comment: Can you show the various layer sizes of your images using docker history <image>? It would be particularly useful to compare a few versions of the image if you have them so that we can see if there are certain layers that are getting exponentially bigger over time.

Comment: are you doing clean checkouts from source control before doing that `COPY . /app` ? i wonder if there's some big stuff hanging around between builds. i assume you're using internet quay, but if you're using inhouse-hosted quay, maybe your registry is not doing so well, causing the slow pushes.

Comment: @RobBlake I did what you said (I hope) and added that information. I also add some more parts of the log, which might help.

Comment: @burnettk yes, clean checkouts are being done.

Comment: Looks like almost all your bandwidth for image copying is coming from your upstream image `microsoft/dotnet:1.1.1-sdk`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by changing the last line in my **build.sh** file:

```
docker push $REPO
```

to

```
docker push $REPO:$TAG
```

I was pushing the entire repository back to the quay server on each build, instead of only the image I just created. Each build would take longer than the last because the repository grows with each image that is added to it.

Comment: I thought it would default to latest instead of pushing everything, but the documentation and testing show otherwise. Nice find, thanks for the follow up!